# how can i get category detail on shipping.php page in magento

Tags: magento

Hi I have to make a custom function in `shipping.php`. I got all the product details but I also want to find the category details.

```
public function getCartDetail(){
    $i=0;
    foreach($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $product[$i]['poroductId'] = $item->getProduct()->getId();
        $product[$i]['price']      = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
        $product[$i]['Name']       = $item->getProduct()->getName();
        $product[$i]['qty']        = $item->getQty();
        $product[$i]['cat_id']     = $item->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
        $i=$i+1;
    }
    return $product;
}
```

This is working on my local system but on server it gives `cat_id` blank.
Is there any other method by which I can find category detail?
Thanks

Comment: When writing your questions there are buttons to help with formatting and a preview just below so you can see how everything looks. Please use them.

Answer (score 0):

If `getCategoryIds()` is returning nothing *sometimes* but not for all servers then try re-indexing the catalog data.

Answer (score 0):

Since a product can be assigned to multiple categories, I suspect getCategoryIds() will be returning an array, rather than a single value.